# Mysql table join taking too much time, while simple select results fast

Tags: mysql, inner-join, innodb

I have an InnoDB table `daily_sales_msr`.

When I run a query from that table without joining, the query returns the output quickly.

But, if I join that table to even with a small table, then it takes too much time. What is the solution to this problem?

For example:

```
SELECT
sku.ssku,
ROUND(SUM(daily_sales_msr.sale), 3) AS sale,
MONTHNAME(daily_sales_msr.date) AS `month`
FROM
daily_sales_msr
INNER JOIN sku ON sku.id = daily_sales_msr.skid
WHERE
daily_sales_msr.date BETWEEN '2018-08-01'
AND '2018-08-08'
GROUP BY
daily_sales_msr.skid
```

This query takes more than 1000s.

Without any joining it takes only 0.15s.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `daily_sales_msr.skid`, `daily_sales_msr.date` and `sku.id` columns?

It would be help if you can paste the structure here, too (it's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command), as well as the number of rows in each table.

Comment: ["4. If you're asking about query performance"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) Please look at other questions re SQL query performance/optimization to see what info has been supplied & requested in comments & used in answers. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for performance be sure you have proper index
in your case you could use a composite index on

```
table daily_sales_msr for  columns  (skid,date)
```

and for SQL you are using group by but some of the column in select  not in group  are not related  to aggregation function 
this in most db engine e in mysql starting form 5.7 is notb alloed  by defualt .. the result for these columns is unpredictable 
so you should add  these columns to group  by

```
SELECT
  sku.ssku,
  ROUND(SUM(daily_sales_msr.sale), 3) AS sale,
  MONTHNAME(daily_sales_msr.date) AS `month`
FROM  daily_sales_msr
INNER JOIN sku ON sku.id = daily_sales_msr.skid
WHERE  daily_sales_msr.date BETWEEN '2018-08-01'  AND '2018-08-08'
GROUP BY  daily_sales_msr.skid, month
```

or use an aggregation function also for these columns

```
SELECT
  sku.ssku,
  ROUND(SUM(daily_sales_msr.sale), 3) AS sale,
  MAX(MONTHNAME(daily_sales_msr.date)) AS `month`
FROM  daily_sales_msr
INNER JOIN sku ON sku.id = daily_sales_msr.skid
WHERE  daily_sales_msr.date BETWEEN '2018-08-01'  AND '2018-08-08'
GROUP BY  daily_sales_msr.skid
```